# How to eject RAMDisk?

Tags: ram, eject

The following commands are how I create a RAMDisk on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/ramdisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024M tmpfs /media/ramdisk
```

But now I have no idea to eject it.

These commands are what I've tried but not work:

```
sudo eject /media/ramdisk
sudo umount /media/ramdisk
```

How to eject RAMDisk properly?

Comment: Define "don't work".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The inverse of `sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /media/ramdisk` is `sudo umount /media/ramdisk`.

The last command will only succeed if no application is using `/media/ramdisk` though. You can use `sudo lsof -n /media/ramdisk` to find out which programs are blocking the mount point.

Comment: Well, it popped up this warning:
`lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/username/.gvfs`
`Output information may be incomplete.`

Comment: That's non-fatal, what make you think that `/media/ramdisk` has not been unmounted? What does `mountpoint /media/ramdisk` tell you? By the way, "unmounting" leaves the directory behind, so you still have to remove the directory after unmounting: `sudo rmdir /media/ramdisk`

Comment: I think it's important to know that you have to specify an absolute path as argument to `sudo lsof -n` otherwise it won't show what you're looking for. `lsof 4.93.2` on Arch.

Comment: At first it seems to be better to delete files that are inside of the ramdisk dir, because I used `umount` and `free -g` shows still through `shared` that the RAM is blocked.